# How to query for Incidents related to a certain service in Service now?

Tags: servicenow

Using CMDB query builder, how to query for all Incident tasks associated with a certain service? I am a beginner and I cannot seem to find an answer to this anywhere. In CMDB I am looking for a class named Service or a Configuration Item named Service, but I can't find any.